# How do I know which are the WSO2 critical security updates?

Tags: security, wso2

When I launch WSO2 API Manager, I get the following notice:

```
There are 177 updates available for the product 'wso2am-3.2.0'.[WARNING] There
are 13 critical security updates for the product 'wso2am-3.2.0'. WSO2 strongly
recommends to apply these updates in production as soon as possible.
```

WSO2 doesn't bundle security updates, so I head to the GitHub issues. The problem is that if I go to the security tag, I don't see anything relevant to the 3.2.0 release: https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues?q=label%3Asecurity+is%3Aclosed

There is one "critical for 3.2.0": https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues?q=label%3ASeverity%2FCritical+label%3AAffected%2F3.2.0

There are two more using this deprecated tag: https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues?q=label%3ASeverity%2FCritical+label%3A3.2.0

So, it seems like what you have to do is look at the 4.0 milestones and cherry-pick those fixes and backport them.

Is there a tag I am missing? Is someone bundling these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the security advisors in here https://docs.wso2.com/display/Security/2020+Advisories